# Filter data returned from helper with regex, using text input as you type

Tags: javascript, regex, meteor

Basically, in my template I have the following code:

```
<div class="normal-padding">
        Quicksearch: <input type="text" id="searchBox"/>
    </div>
    <div class="ui divider"></div>
    {{#each getChildren}}
            <div class="normal-padding">
                <div class="ui two column grid">
                    <div class="column" style="width:60px;">
                        <div class="squaredOne">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="{{_id.toHexString}}" class="selectedChild" id="{{_id.toHexString}}" >
                            <label for="{{_id.toHexString}}"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="column">
                        <label for="{{_id.toHexString}}">{{firstname}} {{lastname}}</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    {{/each}}
```

- Where getChildren is the data coming from mongo.

**My question is this:**
How can I use what's being typed in `input#searchBox` to add/remove members from the `getChildren` helper?
Example:
Typing "ar", will list only the records that start with "ar".

I can figure out the regex required, I'm just not sure how to do this in meteor the correct way. I especially want to stay away from manually manipulating the DOM.

I've tried some filtering packages, but they all query the database again, where I just want the data that's already in the client/browser to be changed.

*In other words, not send a query down the wire again.*

Thanks!

Comment: A far as I can understand, you want to filter the result of getChildren helper, which I think it currently returns something like: return MyCollection.find(); Am I right? I would simple hear the "input" jquery event of #searchBox and set a Session with the typed value. Then, in the helper, instead of doing the previous simple return, filter that find with the value of the given Session value.

Comment: Sweet, that actually works! I've found when it comes to meteor I tend to over-think things. Thanks!